# Elasticsearch - How can I preserve uppercase acronyms while using the lowercase filter?

Tags: tokenize, case-sensitive, analyzer, elasticsearch-2.0, acronym

In Elasticsearch 2.x, how would I distinguish the acronym "CAN" from the common English word "can" while still using the "lowercase" filter in my analzyer (used so searches are case-insensitive)?

The custom analyzer I'm using is:

```
"analyzer": {
    "tight": {
        "type": "custom",
        "tokenizer": "standard",
        "stopwords": "_english_",
        "filter": ["lowercase", "asciifolding"]
    }
}
```

At index time, when the uppercase acronym "CAN" hits my analyzer, it becomes the English word "can". Then when I search for "CAN", I get all documents that have the English word "can" in them. I only want documents that include the uppercase word "CAN". There are likely other acronyms that fall into a similar pattern.

What's the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve it would be to create another analyzer without the `lowercase` token filter and use that analyzer on a sub-field of your main field. It goes like this:

Create an index with two analyzers `tight` and `tight_acronym`. The former is assigned to the `field` and the latter to the `field.acronyms` sub-field:

```
PUT index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "tight": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "asciifolding"
          ]
        },
        "tight_acronym": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "asciifolding"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "properties": {
        "field": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "tight",
          "fields": {
            "acronyms": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "tight_acronym"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then we index two documents:

```
PUT index/test/1
{ "field": "It is worth CAN 300" }
PUT index/test/2
{ "field": "can you do it?" }
```

Then if you search for `CAN` (on the sub-field), you'll get the first document

```
POST index/test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "field.acronyms": "CAN"
    }
  }
}
```

And if you search for `can` (on the main field), you'll get the second document

```
POST index/test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "field": "can"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The first problem I see is that you will also have to search the field with the lowercase filter in order to do a non-case sensitive match, which means that the acronym "CAN" will always match that first criteria. The solution that I'm working on adds a char_filter that replaces the acronym "CAN" with "ccaann", and then I have an acronym replacement list in my code that replaces any occurrences of my acronyms with their lowercase equivalent.

Comment: Fair enough. If you go that route, I suggest using a [synonym token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html) instead, so that you don't need to modify your client code at all. You simply need to curate your synonyms file and you're good to go.

Comment: That's an interesting idea. So if CAN ends up being indexed as "ccaann", then my synonyms would be "CAN,ccaann" is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You also need to make sure that `ignore_case` is set to `false` otherwise `can` and `CAN` would be considered the same.